# How to write XStream converter which write and read via converting to intermediate object?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xstream

I have a class `MyClass`. If I serialize it without implementing custom converter it is not human readable.

I implemented `MyClassDTO` and convertion between `MyClass` and `MyClassDTO`.

`MyClassDTO` is human readable when using XStream standard serialization.

I want to write XStream Converter serialize and deserialize `MyClass`.
Implementation for `Converter.marshal` should be following: convert `MyClass` object to `MyClassDTO` one and call default serialization for `MyClassDTO`.

And for `Converter.unmarshal` : call default deserialization for `MyClassDTO` object and convert it to `MyClass`.

How to implement such behaviour in simple way?

I looked through [XStream Converter Tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html), but have not found what I need.

I need to fill the stubs below:

```
class MatrixConverter<T> : Converter
    where T : new()
{
    public bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(Matrix<T>);
    }

    public void ToXml(object value, Type expectedType, XStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context)
    {
        Matrix<T> matrix = value as Matrix<T>;
        if (matrix == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        // the code which I am asked about should follow here
    }

    public object FromXml(Type expectedType, XStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context)
    {
        Matrix<T> matrix = null;

        // the code which I am asked about should follow here

    }
}
```

Comment: can u post your procedure and tactics...

Comment: which procedure and which tactics?

Comment: I meant by that you should post the code sample which you are trying...

Comment: I added stub in question, hope it make my question more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming

```
MatrixDTO m = new MatrixDTO( matrix );
```

converts from your internal matrix type to the DTO.

```
public void ToXml(object value, Type expectedType, 
    XStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context)
{
    context.convertAnother(new MatrixDTO( matrix ));
}

public Object FromXml(Type expectedType, 
    XStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context)
{
    return context.convertAnother(context.currentObject(), MatrixDTO.class);
}
```

In the unmarshalling case you may have to insert it manually into the context.currentObject(). Haven't tried that myself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: seems correct. But I have not tried because already implemented in other way. Thanks.